# Application of intermediate value theorem in context of definite integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a,b]$. Then I have to show that there exists $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^x f=\int_x^b f$.
I understand it intuitively. It says that for any interval $[a,b]$, we can find a point  $c$ in between(in some cases, the end points of the interval) such that area of the curve lying in between $x=a$ and $x=c$ is exactly equal to area of the curve in between $x=c$ and $x=b$. i.e. there is a point where the area is exactly halved.
But I am having a problem proving it analytically in a rigors manner.
There is a hint that it can be proved using intermediate value theorem. But I do not know how to do it. Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\int_a^xf-\int_x^bf$. Then $g(a)=\int_a^bf$ and $g(b)=-\int_a^bf$. So…

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Consider the function $I(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt $ on the interval $[a,b]$.   What is the value of $I(a)$?  $I(b)$?  now use the IVT

Comment: $I(a)=0$ and $I(b)=$ value of definite integral of $f$ in between limits $a$ and $b$ which could be anything positive, negative or zero. How do I apply IVT ?

Comment: You want to find a point where it is exactly half the full value.  Is half the full value between 0 and the full value?